# Do $\mathbb{N}=\left\{1,2,\dots\right\}$ and $\mathbb{N}_0=\left\{0,1,2,\dots\right\}$ determine the same algebra?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, logic

In what follows we shall assume the conventional interpretation of
the symbols $'=','\ne'$ and the other logical symbols used to formulate
 definitions. Lowercase Latin letters $a,b,\dots,z$
will designate *number variables*. The notation $\mathcal{P}\left[n\right]$
represents a *proposition regarding a number variable* $n$. By a *number*
we mean an element of the set $\mathbb{N}$ defined by the following
axioms:

I. $1\in\mathbb{N}.$

II. $\underset{a}{\forall}\exists a^{\prime}\in\mathbb{N}.$

III. $a^{\prime}=b^{\prime}\implies a=b.$

IV. $\underset{a}{\forall}a^{\prime}\ne1.$

V. $\left(\mathcal{P}\left[1\right]\land\underset{n}{\forall}\left(\mathcal{P}\left[n\right]\implies\mathcal{P}\left[n^{\prime}\right]\right)\right)\implies\underset{n}{\forall}\mathcal{P}\left[n\right].$

The object $a^{\prime}$ is called the *successor of* $a$. That is my rendering of the axioms attributed to Peano.

We now define the set of functions

$$
\Phi=\left\{ \varphi_{a}:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\backepsilon\varphi_{a}\left[x^{\prime}\right]\equiv\varphi_{a}\left[x\right]^{\prime}\right\} .
$$

For notational convenience we also define

$$
\left[\_+\right]:\mathbb{N}_{1}\to\Phi
$$

so that

$$
\left[a+\_\right]\equiv\varphi_{a},
$$

to be interpreted as
$$
a+b:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\text{ where }a+b\equiv\varphi_{a}\left[b\right].
$$

From the above definitions we may prove the associative and commutative
properties of addition. By defining the symbols $'<'$ and $'>'$
as meaning

$$
a<b\implies\underset{c}{\exists}a+c=b\text{ and }a>b\equiv b<a,
$$

we may define (or show) the *well ordering* of $\mathbb{N}.$

If we now define the notation $\bar{a}$ to mean $a<\bar{a},$ we
have 
$$
\neg\underset{x}{\exists}x+\bar{a}=a.
$$

That is, $\mathbb{N}$ contains no negative numbers. We also have
the condition
$$
\underset{a,b}{\forall}a+b\ne a.
$$

Which says $0\notin\mathbb{N},$ or that *there is no additive identity
element* in our set of numbers.

If we define numbers to be the set $\mathbb{N}_{0}$ by replacing
the symbol $'1'$ with the symbol $'0'$, without bestowing additional
properties to $'0'$, we arrive at exactly the same algebraic structure
as we have for $\mathbb{N}.$

Let us assume we agree that by the *natural numbers* we intend
the most fundamental complete set of numbers of interest to a mathematician.
We shall further assume that the only reasonable choices are between
$\mathbb{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\mathbb{N}_{0}$ as defined above. To
argue that it is preferable to choose $\mathbb{N}_{0}$ rather than
$\mathbb{N}$ presupposes that the element which is not a successor
has a different interpretation when symbolized as $'1'$ than when
symbolized $'0'.$

So my question is this: **is the basic algebraic structure intended
by** $\mathbb{\mathbb{N}}=\left\{ 1,2,\dots,0\right\} $ **distinct form
that intended by** $\mathbb{N}_{0}=\left\{ 0,1,2,\dots\right\} ?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, $n\mapsto n+1$ is an isomorphism between these two, hence both have the same logical structure.
If you prefer to always work with $\Bbb N$, you may want to introduce he operation $+^*$, where $a+^* b$ is the unique $c$ with $c'=a+b$. Then $+^*$ is associative, abeliam amd *does* have a neutral element - an operation that sometimes comes in handy. If you need suc an operation on $\Bbb N$, you can use $+^*$ - or work in the isomorphic $\Bbb N_0$, where $+^*$ becomes ordinary addition. This makes $(\Bbb N,+^*)$ isomorphic to $(\Bbb N_0,+)$, but of course $(\Bbb N,+)$ and $(\Bbb N_0,+)$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: Hence, by process of extension, one may begin with $\left(\mathbb{N},+\right)$ and arrive at $\left(\mathbb{N}_0,+\right)$.  In that approach, '0' is "invented" to solve a specific kind of equation in the same way that $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is.